# http api on google cloud using app engine or cloud function

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

i want to build an api using python and host it on google cloud. api will basically read some data in bucket and then do some processing on it and return the data back. i am hoping that i can read the data in memory and when request comes, just process it and send response back to serve it with low latency. assume i will read few thousand records from some database/storage and when request comes process and send 10 back based on request parameters. i dont want to make connection/read storage when the request comes as it will take time and i want to serve as fast as possible.

will google cloud function work for this need? or shoudl i go with app engine. (basically i want to be able to read the data once and hold it for incoming requests). data mostly will be less than 1-2 gb (max)

thanks,
Manish

Comment: Can you precise if the data are statics or if the data can change? My concern is: if you have 2 instances (Cloud Run or App Engine) running concurrently, can they embedded the data in their memory, or do they need to share a same memory space to take into account the data updates?

Comment: data is static @guillaumeblaquiere. also lets say i want two endpoint that refer to two different static datasets and each function really refers to one dataset. how do i structure the project so each function as only one set of static data loaded. i obviourly dont want to load that data on request time as it will give horrible latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the static data with your function code. Increase the Cloud Functions memory to allow it to load in memory the data to keep them warm and for having a very fast access to it.

Then, you have 2 way to achieve it:

- Load the data at startup. You load them only once, the first call has a high latency to download (from GCS for instance) and load the data in memory. The advantage is: in case of data update, you don't have to redeploy your function, only update the data in their location. At the next function start, the new data will be loaded
- Deploy the function with the static data in the deployment. This time the startup time is much faster (no download), only the data to load in memory. But when you want to update the data, you have to redeploy your function.

A final word if you have 2 set of static data, you must have 2 functions. The responsibility is different, so the deployment is different.

Comment: thats what i ended up doing.